# Unable to login to spring security with oAuth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

I am not able to login to my appication and always getting the error as Unauthorized.

Below is my application.properties file.

```
#data source properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:spring_boot_oauth2
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/data.sql
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# JPA properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.openInView=false
spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

#web server
server.port=9191


#Application specific
authentication.oauth.clientid=onlyfullstack
authentication.oauth.secret=$2y$12$loLVygQVJrwOUWsQNFXV4.HlhAwW2B6quFpnmHQVSVOQGPabMf2/u
authentication.oauth.tokenValidityInSeconds=180066

logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG,stdout
```

**OAuth2Configuration file :**

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                    .disable()
                    .headers()
                    .frameOptions().disable()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/hello/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated();

        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String ENV_OAUTH = "authentication.oauth.";
        private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "authentication.oauth.clientid";
        private static final String PROP_SECRET = "authentication.oauth.secret";
        private static final String PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = "authentication.oauth.tokenValidityInSeconds";

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        Environment environment;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("******************* : "+ environment.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID) +", ++"+environment.getProperty(PROP_SECRET)+"");
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient(environment.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities(Authorities.ROLE_ADMIN.name(), Authorities.ROLE_USER.name())
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")

                    .secret(environment.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(environment.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 180011));
        }

    }

}
```

When I hit the below URL I am not getting the access :
http://localhost:9191/oauth/token with Basic Auth as onlyfullstack / $2y$12$loLVygQVJrwOUWsQNFXV4.HlhAwW2B6quFpnmHQVSVOQGPabMf2/u

and in body I am passing the username and password as saurabh / only which I am storing in the DB. But still I am not getting the access to the resource.

To debug it, I have added a debugger in DAOAuthenticationProvider class and I saw the actual password : only and encoded password as : $2y$12$loLVygQVJrwOUWsQNFXV4.HlhAwW2B6quFpnmHQVSVOQGPabMf2/u are matching and its giving false value. but when i check it externally by calling passwordEncoder.match method its giving me true. can you please suggest me what is going wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: I am using spring boot starter security with version 2.0.3.RELEASE and Spring oAuth2 version as 2.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please decode the `authentication.oauth.secret` value and use it.